Syntax To Force CRC Placement in Hex File
I can't find the correct syntax to force the CY MCU ELF Tool to create a CRC-signed hex file that places the CRC at __cy_app_signature address that I specify in the linker script. I have added the following post-build instruction to my makefile:
POSTBUILD+=\
        $(CY_TOOL_cymcuelftool_EXE_ABS) -S $(MTB_TOOLS__OUTPUT_CONFIG_DIR)/$(APPNAME).elf CRC --output $(MTB_TOOLS__OUTPUT_CONFIG_DIR)/$(APPNAME)_crc.elf --hex $(MTB_TOOLS__OUTPUT_CONFIG_DIR)/$(APPNAME)_crc.hex && \
        $(CY_TOOL_cymcuelftool_EXE_ABS) -P $(MTB_TOOLS__OUTPUT_CONFIG_DIR)/$(APPNAME)_crc.elf --output $(MTB_TOOLS__OUTPUT_CONFIG_DIR)/$(APPNAME)_crc.cyacd2

This instruction creates a hex file called "MyApplication_crc.hex", but there is no CRC at the specified address visible when I view the hex file. Anyone see what I'm missing?

Look at the output from the post-build commands because the output may explain the error.  Should it be .cy_app_signature rather than _cy_app_signature?  Is the .cy_app_signature section big enough to contain the CRC (4 bytes)?  If larger then the CRC may be at the end of the section rather than the beginning.
